# MigLayout: Only window displayed when trying fullscreen

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

Here is code:

```
ScreenHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height,
ScreenWidth = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;

JFrame MainFrame = new JFrame();
MainFrame.setSize(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
MainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
MainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
MainFrame.setVisible(true);

/* When set to false, all buttons and boxes are displayed, 
   otherwise only the main window appears */ 
MainFrame.setUndecorated(true); 

Container Pane = Frame.getContentPane();
Pane.setLayout(new MigLayout());
initLoginPanel(Pane);
```

The function that lays out the controls:

```
private void initLoginPanel(Container Obj) 
{
    JPanel LoginContainer = new JPanel();
    LoginContainer.setLayout(new MigLayout());

    Obj.add(LoginContainer, "pos 0.5al 0.5al");

    JLabel  uNameLabel = new JLabel("Username");
    JTextField uNameBox = new JTextField();

    JLabel uPassLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    JTextField uPassBox = new JTextField();

    JButton LoginButton = new JButton("Login", 90, 26);
    LoginContainer.add(uNameLabel, "wrap");
    LoginContainer.add(uNameBox, "span");
    LoginContainer.add(uPassLabel, "wrap");
    LoginContainer.add(uPassBox, "span");
    LoginContainer.add(LoginButton, "");
}
```

If, in the above code, `MainFrame.setUndecorated(false)` is used, it works fine but no full screen. That is the title bar, close, minimize and maximize buttons are displayed.

**Question:**
1. How can I get the components working in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Please, don't make excessive use of code blocks. Try to explain your problem and _complement_ your post with _small_ code snippets. Thanks!

Comment: @jmendeth I have given the code so that people can just copy paste into their IDE and see for themselves (Assuming `main()` etc are produced by the IDE). As for explanation, the couple sentences just above the question, I guess, should be enough. :)

Comment: Why did you tag your question with MigLayout? MigLayout is obviously not the problem here!

Comment: @jfpoilpret Then what is the problem?

Comment: MigLayout is not in charge of handling the full screen mode or decoration of the frames, that's the responsibility of Swing and the look and feel. If you provided a SSCCE, then it would be easier to get help; there's probably a problem in code you didn't show here.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: @jfpoilpret Please read the second comment on the list (the one from me)

Comment: @jfpoilpret Also, I am pin pointing MigLayout because the code works fine when adapted for other Layout Managers.

Comment: @check123 if other layout managers work well, then you should definitely post 2 SSCCE in your question: the one that doesn't work (with MigLayout) and the one that works (with another LM). I insist on having SSCCE because I am sure both examples you mention have other differences than just the LayoutManager...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. **The position of `setVisible`**
   Showing the frame must be the **last step**;
   first you must *setup* your frame and *add* his content.
2. **The call to `initLoginPanel`**
   Your code is doing incorrect things. Why don't you add the components *directly* to the frame? i.e.

   ```
   initLoginPanel( YourJFrame );
   ```

**Fixed, simplified code:**

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main window");

frame.setSize( Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize() );
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setUndecorated(false);

initLoginPanel(frame);

frame.setVisible(true); //FINALLY show the JFrame!
```

Comment: I had tried it earlier and rectified it again on your recommendation but still does not work!

Comment: In my first try of your code, I overlooked calling `initLoginPanel()` before `setVisible`. Changing that has fixed the situation. Thanks. +1 & Correct.